# Number of hours to HH:MM with Moment.js (or without)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have very simple problem, but couldn't find good simple DRY solution. I want to convert number of hours to `HH:MM` format. My try with Moment.js is:

```
var hours = 10.5
var hour_string = moment(hours*3600*1000).format('HH:MM')
```

But unfortunately I get:

```
"11:01"
```

and have no idea why. Of course my wanted result is `"10:30"`.

I'd like just do it in the easiest way, similar as I can do in Rails:

```
Time.at(hours*3600).utc.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, I found the reason. `"MM"` means months, not minutes, which are `"mm"`. And the hour shift was caused by timezones, which we can omit using the `utc` function. The final solution is:

```
moment.utc(hours*3600*1000).format('HH:mm')
```

Comment: Please note that this fails for numbers over 24 as moment then refers to this value as 1 day.

e.g.

`moment.utc(24*3600*1000).format('HH:mm') => '00:00' `

Answer (score -1):

```
let hour = 10;
let minute = 30;

moment({ hour, minute }).format('HH:mm');

// output: 10:30
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the time zone issue and ignores the fact that OP is using a float for hours, not hours and minutes.